# using spring boot application as a dependency in another project

Tags: spring, spring-boot, deployment, jar, dependencies

Hi im pretty new to spring boot. I have a spring boot application with controllers, services and dao(say A). Is there any way i can use this application as a dependency such a way that when i run another spring boot application(Say B) with the A as dependency.
I must be able to run the controllers,Services and Dao in both A and B.
Is this possible?
If Possible how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can certainly do that ! Use `exec` plugin like this

For e.g. in Service A `pom.xml` mention this

```
<build>
    ...
    <plugins>
        ...
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <classifier>exec</classifier>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Post `mvn clean install` you will see a version of your service A. Pick up that version and

Use Service A as a dependency in Service B by specifying dependency tag like below

```
<dependencies>
<dependency>
<groupId> com.yourAppGroup </groupId>
<artifactId> com.serviceA </artifactId>
<version> 1.0-Snapshot </version>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I suggest to not use Controllers/services from dependency, instead only DAO. Service specific code should be in service only !